# Is is better to have more global object constructors or should they be grouped into one object?

Tags: javascript

I may have gotten some of the lingo wrong, but here's what I'm asking:

Which of these is semantically better?

Using multiple constructors for similar objects, using a prefix (Parent) to group them.

```
function ParentChildA (val) {
    this.val = val+'a';
}

function ParentChildB (val) {
    this.val = val+'b';
}

new ParentChildA (val);
new ParentChildB (val);
```

Or, using an empty Parent object to group them under one object.

```
Parent = {};

Parent.childA = function(val)  {
    this.val = val+'a';
}

Parent.childB = function(val)  {
    this.val = val+'b';
}

new Parent.ChildA (val);
new Parent.ChildB (val);
```

Is it bad for to create a blank container object for the sake of just grouping? I am trying to be a good little coder and not pollute the global namespace cause the big kids said it's bad.

Comment: Even if wanted to group them, you should *definitely* not group them into a prototype object.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "similar objects"? Are you looking for inheritance? Btw, the two example functions you've shown are exactly equivalent.

Comment: edited my code a bit based on your comments, hope that clears it up a little

Comment: Still you would usually group them into an *object*, not a function. (Though in some cases an already existing function object is suited for it as well) Use a simple object literal.

Comment: You're totally right, I'm just trying to wrap my head around using objects in this way so I got a little mixed up

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're doing with them. Objects should always be structured for maintainability and usability, so for your particular case ask yourself: which is going to be easier to use and maintain?

There are no hard and fast definitive answers when it comes to object design in any language, but there are some general principles to think about as you plan your structure.

1. You want to keep intuitively similar things together.
2. You don't want any object to have so much complexity that:

   1. Looking for a child object takes too long a time.
   2. The names of children start to collide.
3. You want messages between objects to be simple and minimal. This means that if you have say a "person" object, you might want to have `person.run()` and `person.walk()` instead of having to pass an object as a message to another object like `run(person)` and `walk(person)`. OTOH you might have so many children to the person object that it makes sense to have `person.movement.run()` and `person.movement.walk()` so that the list of things under person is of reasonable size.

Ideally you want to stop for a couple minutes, brainstorm and plan out the things your object should do and be used for and then design something that fits that use case. There will inevitably be additions and changes, but just trying to plan a bit helps limit refactoring.

If you're asking about performance differences, that's not my expertise, but in general for most things we have enough processing power these days for that to be negligible.

If you want a more in depth guide on design, there are a lot of good resources out there. [Bob Martin's Principles of OOD is a good place to start](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).

Comment: But if you added a dog object that was pretty similar to person, it also has .walk() and .run(), would you group them together? Or only if there are a lot like if we added 10 other animals? Keep in mind these would would all be in the global namespace if not grouped, that's especially my reasoning for doing so.

Comment: Well what does run() actually do? Does each animal have a unique run? humans and dogs certainly have different runs() if we're talking about speed or movement pattern. OTOH if run() is just executing a displacement vector for an object in a space, then you'd probably have animal.run() and animal.type = person or maybe a global run()

Like I tried to say, there are no perfect answers. You have to think about what makes sense for how you will be using the objects.